# ASP.NET MVC Jquery Ajax post form serialize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Ajax function

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: { model: $(this).serialize(), locations: getCheckedLocation(), reports: getCheckedReports() },
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                complete: function () {

                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#user_operations_container').html(result);
                    setTimeout(function () { LoadAction('@Url.Action("GetAllUsers", "User")') }, 1000);
                    $("#widgets ul li a").removeClass("link_active");
                    $("#widgets ul li:first-child a").addClass("link_active");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

functions that are using in ajax data attribute

```
function getCheckedLocation() {
    var nodes = $('#tt_location').tree('getChecked');
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (s != '') s += ',';
        s += nodes[i].text;
    }
    return s;
}

function getCheckedReports() {
    var nodes = $('#tt_reports').tree('getChecked');
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (s != '') s += ',';
        s += nodes[i].text;
    }

    return s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div> // there are html helpers for model (dropdownlistfor, textboxfor,...)
</div>
<div> // checkbox tree (#tt_location)
</div>
<div> // checkbox tree (#tt_reports)
</div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _EditUser(UserViewModel model,string locations,string reports)
{
    // model = null
    // locations and reports are expected. (not null)
}
```

Question

Why model is null? 
When I use ajax data attribute like this = `data: $(this).serialize(),` , It works model is not null.

How can I post model, with additional data (locations,reports).

I hope I can explain. Thanks...

Comment: You dont need `model:$(this).serialize()` you can simply pass it as `$(this).serialize()`. I'm not expert with ajax but it worked for me

Comment: I think `reports: getCheckedReports` has to be `reports: getCheckedReports()` may be a typo

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` works alone. But with additional data, It does not work. for example `{ $(this).serialize(), locations: getCheckedLocation(), reports: getCheckedReports() }` is not working. Because of syntax error.

Comment: What happens if you change the `contentType` to `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @TimBJames, form is posting to `_EditUser` that is `[HttpGet]` method.

Comment: May be you can try with `$(this).serializeArray();` and pass the additional data. Can you give a try ?

Comment: @Karthik, after your suggestion, model is not null, but its values are null.

Comment: your form should contains all the data allowing to the Binder to instanciate the arguements of the controller. In your case you must use only $(this).Serialize() and be sure that your form contains inputs named locations and reports. Other wise the object given to data will be serialized as an url string and web server will receive a serialization of serialized data.

Comment: @tschmit007, I use jquery tree plugin, so checkboxes are not check type. they are span element. So if I serilize form, I cant get them.

Comment: can you try like this `$('this').serialize() + "&locations=" + getCheckedLocation() "&reports=" + getCheckedReports()`

Comment: @Karthik, it works without syntax error like this : `$(this).serialize() + "&locations=" + getCheckedLocation() + "&reports=" + getCheckedReports()` Thanks a lot. If you write your comment as answer, I will accept that. Great Thanks.

Comment: @Karthik , Will you write last comment as answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 data:$('this').serialize() + "&locations=" + getCheckedLocation() "&reports=" + getCheckedReports()
```

It will work.

Hope it helps